# Postgres: Select min/max... over the result of another select

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have a select query like this:

```
SELECT name, SUM(table1.tons_of_data * (table2.tons_of_data * (1/1000)) AS value
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table1.tons_of_data IS NOT NULL
AND table2.tons_of_data IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY value
```

Resulting in something like:

```
| name | value |
________________
   a.      1
   b.      2
   c.      3
```

With more than 1M rows as results

Then I need to calculate min, max, percentiles OVER the value column output. I tried of something like:

```
SELECT name, SUM(table1.tons_of_data * (table2.tons_of_data * (1/1000)) AS value,
MIN(table1.tons_of_data * (table2.tons_of_data * (1/1000)) as min
...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table1.tons_of_data IS NOT NULL
AND table2.tons_of_data IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY value
```

Wrongly resulting in

```
 | name | value |. min | max |
 ______________________________
    a.      1       1.     1
    b.      2.      2.     2
    c.      3.      3.     3
```

In a fantasy world, what I would like to have is:

```
| name | value |
________________
   a.      1
   b.      2
   c.      3
```

And then, somehow the result of the MIN, MAX, etc over the value column like this

```
| min | max |
________________
   1      3
```

Is there any way to achieve what I need without persisting the result of the first query and avoiding repeating the maths within the query? (also avoiding the min/max results over each cell, which is totally useless)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case for using a [cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) :

```
With list AS
(
SELECT name, SUM(table1.tons_of_data * (table2.tons_of_data * (1/1000)) AS value
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table1.tons_of_data IS NOT NULL
AND table2.tons_of_data IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY name
)
SELECT name, value, min(value) over w AS min, max(value) over w AS max
  FROM list
WINDOW w AS ()
```

Comment: @Eduouard H. Thanks for your reply! But in your approach, I would need to repeat the same computation (which is quite expensive IRL) twice, one to get the table result, and then the aggregate values

Some twerking to your approach would be possible to somehow avoid repeating the same calculus twice?
Thanks!

Comment: @SeekanDestroy : I don't understand why you "would need to repeat the same computation twice" ? can you please explain where is there "the same calculus twice" ? I don't see where is the repetition in the proposed solution.

Comment: Because I need both results, as I stated in the question: the name & value table, and then the aggregations (min, max, percentiles) over the results of the first query
Your solution retrieves the aggregations of the 'internal' query
So I'll need to launch first the query between parentesis, and then your solution to get the job done

Comment: @SeekanDestroy : I have updated the answer to that you can retrieve the names, values and min, max at the same time.

Comment: Shame on me didnt realize the change before. This is brilliant, thank you so much.

Comment: Saldy OVER is not supported for ordered-set aggregate percentile_cont
but I think I can work over this. Thank you so much!